# fancybox wrong image quantity with slick slider

Tags: javascript, fancybox, slick.js

I'm using fancybox to display image gallery.

I have this layout:

```
    <div class="avatar">
        <a class="avatar-item" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Caption #1" href="img/avatars/jessica1.jpeg">
            <img src="./img/avatars/jessica1.jpeg" width="145" height="145" alt="">
        </a>
        <a class="avatar-item" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Caption #2" href="img/avatars/jessica2.jpeg">
            <img src="./img/avatars/jessica2.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

And when I click on preview - gallery popup occurs, but it shows **4** images instead of **2**. I included fancybox via data-attributes, without javascript. Tried magnific popup with gallery option - got same result. 
link `href` attribute value and internal image `src` attribute are the same.
I don't have a thumbnail, display image cropped with css.

Hee is CSS:

```
.avatar {
    &.slick-dotted.slick-slider {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    a.avatar-item {
        width: 146px;
        height: 146px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    width: 146px;
    height: 146px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    img {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: and your js code? css? version of fancybox?

Comment: fancyBox v3.0.47
I didn't use javascript to trigger fancybox, only data-attributes in html page.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. I use slick-slider before with infinite: true parameter, which creates an extra slides, so I got count slides x2

Comment: I had the same problem, but in the sa me time I wanted to leave an infinite loop in Slick-Carousel, so I removed `data-fancybox` on a page load from cloned images: `$('.slick-cloned').removeAttr('data-fancybox');`.

Comment: @kwiat1990 Doesn't that just get rid of the link altogether, though? I'm assuming you'd still want to launch Fancy Box, even on a duplicate slide. One option is to target the cloned elements and change the data-fancybox property to something else, i.e. "data-fancybox="duplicate". It might mess up the pagination/numbering in fancybox, though, as cloned elements appear before and after the current item, but I suppose it's a better option than nothing.

Comment: @Carter, unfortunaltely, nowadays I don't remember that code very well, so I can't go in details. However, I was pleased with how it worked back then, so I assume that in my case it was a good solution.

Comment: @JordanCarter a bit late to the party. In my specific case the cloned elements appear outside the screen so kwiat1990's solution was sufficient. But whenever you might want to launch fancybox on the clones, give them a `data-fancybox-trigger` attribute. It's designed especially for dupe images. `$('.slick-cloned a').removeAttr('data-fancybox'); $('.slick-cloned a').attr('data-fancybox-trigger', 'gallery');` Also, see https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage.

Comment: I just did something like this which is a bit simpler: `$( '.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned) [data-fancybox="gallery"]' ).fancybox( { .. } );`

Comment: @JKL, thanks a lot for your comment! `data-fancybox-trigger` attribute also works in fancybox - version 4! but there is no reference for it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the _run function. Now duplicate images are removed from the gallery and still the correct key is returned. Furthermore I have the possibility to arrange the images in any order via data-facybox position.

So it is also possible to use the infinity version of the slick slider.

```
function _run(e, opts) {
  var tempItems,
    items       = [],
    newItem,
    reOrder,
    duplicates  = false,
    pos,
    index       = 0,
    $target,
    value,
    instance;

// Avoid opening multiple times
  if (e && e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    return;
  }

  e.preventDefault();

  opts = opts || {};

  if (e && e.data) {
    opts = mergeOpts(e.data.options, opts);
  }

  $target = opts.$target || $(e.currentTarget).trigger("blur");
  instance = $.fancybox.getInstance();

  if (instance && instance.$trigger && instance.$trigger.is($target)) {
    return;
  }

  if (opts.selector) {
    tempItems = $(opts.selector);
  } else {
    // Get all related items and find index for clicked one
    value = $target.attr("data-fancybox") || "";
    if (value) {
      tempItems = e.data ? e.data.items : [];
      tempItems = tempItems.length ? tempItems.filter('[data-fancybox="' + 
      value + '"]') : $('[data-fancybox="' + value + '"]');
    } else {
      tempItems = [$target];
    }
  }

  if (tempItems.length > 1) {
    $.each(tempItems, function(key, item) {  // prevents duplicate images in the gallery
      newItem = false;
      if (typeof item !== 'undefined') {
        if (items.length > 0) {
          var found = items.filter(function (items) { return items.href == 
          item.href });
          if (found.length == 0) {
            newItem     = true;
          } else {
            duplicates  = true;
          }
        } else {
          newItem = true;
        }
      }
      if (newItem) {
        // Sort if the attribute data-fancybox-pos exists
        if ($(item).data('fancybox-pos')) {
          reOrder = true;
          pos     = $(item).data('fancybox-pos') - 1;
          if (pos in items) {
            tempItem    = items[pos];
            items[pos]  = item;
            items.push(tempItem);
          } else {
            items[pos]  = item;
          }
        } else {
          items.push(item);
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    items = tempItems;
  }

  if (duplicates || reOrder) {
    // find correct index if there were duplicates
    $.each(items, function(key, item) {
      if (item.href == $target[0].href) {
        index = key;
      }
    });
  } else {
    index = $(items).index($target);
  }

  // Sometimes current item can not be found
  if (index < 0) {
    index = 0;
  }

  instance = $.fancybox.open(items, opts, index);

  // Save last active element
  instance.$trigger = $target;
}
```